# Sencha Touch toolbar height

Tags: sencha-touch-2, toolbar, sencha-touch-theming

I dynamically create a bottom toolbar but it has its default height no matter the value I give to the height property. I tried the purcentage, pixels, simple numbers but nothing works.

```
myComponent.add({
                        xtype:'toolbar',

                        autoDestroy:true,
                        docked:'bottom',
                        bottom:0,

                        width:'100%',
                        height:'5px',

                        margin:'0 0 0 0',
                        padding:'0 0 0 0',

                        layout:{
                            pack:'middle',
                            align:'middle'
                        }
});
```

Comment: I also tried the maxHeight config but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the `minHeight` property.

A working Example from my Code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.FailureBar', {
    extend : 'Ext.Toolbar',
    alias : 'widget.failureBar',
    config : {
        docked : 'bottom',
        minHeight : '30px',
        zIndex : 1,
        cls : 'failureBar'
    }
});
```